# Adding ionic pages to already created Angular app [ionic]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I've successfully converted the angular app into an ionic app which can run on iOS and Android.  Now I am trying to grab the lifecycle methods (ionViewDidLoad, ionviewdidleave, etc) when the components appear/disappear.  The app currently does not have any ionic pages,  do I need to add a page(s) to get these lifecycle methods?  I've been doing ionic for a week or so, so please keep the flame on low.

Thanks

Comment: which ionic version? If ionic 2/3 they need to be ionicpage

Comment: im currently on ionic 4

Comment: ionic 4 uses [angular router](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/concepts#navigation).. So you will need to depend on angular lifecycle methods not ionViewDidLoad. Check https://medium.com/@paulstelzer/ionic-4-and-the-lifecycle-hooks-4fe9eabb2864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 4 has deprecated the previous `IonicPage` and its navigation. It now uses the default [navigation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/concepts#navigation) of the template you are using. In case of angular its [angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

> Previous versions of Ionic shipped with our own custom router, but in order to provide the best tooling and developer experience we have since moved to using the framework's recommended router.

Ionic 4 provides the hooks:

`ionViewWillEnter`, `ionViewDidEnter`, `ionViewWillLeave`, and `ionViewDidLeave`
Also check migration guide [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration#lifecycle-events).

You can use the [angular lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) hooks in place of the older ionic lifecycle hooks like `ngOnInit` in place of `ionViewDidLoad`. Use angular's router guard instead of ionic's navguard.